# Typesetting fractions in an augmented matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to typeset fractions in display math mode within an augmented matrix. The "`2`" in the denominator of one row touches the "`1`" in the numerator of the next row, which is not appropriate. How do I increase the interline spacing?

How would I typeset the fractions in text mode?

I would like the code using the `array` environment. Any code using the `bmatrix` environment that is rendered similarly to that using the `array` environment would be nice to see as well.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccc|r@{}}
1   &   0   &   -1  &   a \\
0   &   1   &   0   &   \dfrac{1}{2} \, a + \dfrac{1}{2} \, b + \dfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0   &   0   &   1   &  -\dfrac{1}{2} \, a - \dfrac{1}{2} \, b + \dfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Normal `\frac`s wouldn't touch, why are you using the bigger `\dfrac`s?

Comment: Change `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` to `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`?

Comment: @Mico Without fractions in the first row, the interline spacing between the first two rows is too big.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire - Please see the answer I posted a short while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid right alignment in the last column.

I have three proposals: the best, in my opinion, is the last one; the worst is the middle one.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1   &   0   &   -1  &   a \\[1ex]
0   &   1   &   0   &  \hphantom{-}\frac{1}{2} a + \frac{1}{2} b + \frac{1}{2} c \\[1ex]
0   &   0   &   1   &  -\frac{1}{2} a - \frac{1}{2} b + \frac{1}{2} c \\[0.5ex]
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1   &   0   &   -1  &   a \\[2ex]
0   &   1   &   0   &  \hphantom{-}\dfrac{1}{2} a + \dfrac{1}{2} b + \dfrac{1}{2} c \\[2ex]
0   &   0   &   1   &  -\dfrac{1}{2} a - \dfrac{1}{2} b + \dfrac{1}{2} c \\[1ex]
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
1   &   0   &   -1  &   a \\
0   &   1   &   0   &  (a + b + c)/2 \\
0   &   0   &   1   &  (-a - b + c)/2
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for also getting rid of the `\,` spacing directives.

Comment: I appreciate that you provided three options! And I agree with your assessment.

Answer (score 4):

For numerical coefficients, I would first use medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`, and the `empheq` environment, from the homonymous package, next, increase the value of `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrack, right =\empheqrbrack]{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.75}
\begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|l@{\,}}
1 & 0 & 0 & \phantom{-}a \\
0 & \phantom{-}1 & -1 & \phantom{-}\mfrac{1}{2} \, a + \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\mfrac{1}{2} \, a - \mfrac{1}{2} \, b + \mfrac{1}{2} \, c
\end{array}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made an edit to my code. I only have `"a"` in last column of the first row. So, the interline spacing between the first and second rows is too big.

Comment: I also changed the `"0"` in the second row, third column to `"-1"`.

Comment: That requires some changes for a nice alignment in the matrix. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I do not have fractions in the first row. I have `"a"` in last column of the first row.

Comment: That was not the case initially? I didn't see it. Anyway, here is a  corrected version. Does that befit you?

Comment: Yes, I made an edit. The augmented matrix looks very nice.

Comment: I am row reducing this matrix.  How do I its reduced, row echelon matrix next to it - separated by a comma and some space like `\qquad \qquad`?

Comment: Yes, why not? Or you can use  an ` align*` environment with two columns (i.e.  3 `&`). (in this case the argument for the empheq environment should be  `{align*}`).

Comment: I am not getting the right brace of the first matrix and the left brace of the second matrix with `... \end{array}, \qquad \quad \begin{array}{@{\,}ccc|l@{\,}} ...` .

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `nicematrix` package. You could to shift the a more at the right with the command `\mkern-180mu`. For example with `\mkern-150mu` the character `a` move more to the right.

NB: I have not seen the correct comment of the user **@Mico** for the set `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
$\left[\begin{NiceArray}{CCC|R}
1 & 0 & -1 & \mkern-180mu a \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{2}  a + \dfrac{1}{2}  b + \dfrac{1}{2}  c \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{1}{2}  a - \dfrac{1}{2}  b + \dfrac{1}{2}  c
\end{NiceArray}\right]$
\end{document}
```

Without `\mkern-180mu`
you will have this output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using instead another package `spalign` (+ the option `mathtools`) you will have:

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\[\spaligndelims{[}{]} \spalignaugmatn[c]{1}{1 0 -1 a; 0 1 0 {\dfrac{1}{2}  a + \dfrac{1}{2}  b + \dfrac{1}{2}  c}; 0 0 1 {\dfrac{1}{2}  a + \dfrac{1}{2}  b + \dfrac{1}{2}  c};} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a valid reason for using `\dfrac` in this array. Changing all instances of `\dfrac` to `\frac`, getting rid of the equally unmotivated `\,` directives, increasing the value of `\arraystretch` from 1.2 to 1.333, changing the column type of the fourth column from `r` to `l`, and inserting a couple of judiciously chosen `\phantom` directives yields the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.333}
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}rrr|l@{}}
1 & 0 &-1 & \phantom{-\frac{1}{2}}a \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \phantom{-}\frac{1}{2}a + \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}c \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2}a - \frac{1}{2}b + \frac{1}{2}c
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```